# Why MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED Android action is ignored by the content scheme

Tags: android, broadcast, intentfilter

I have a intent-filter declaration in the manifest for a broadcast.

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

The problem is when I remove the `<data android:scheme="content"/>` the **MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED** action is received otherwise no.

What does the data tag in this case? Can't really understand from the documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<data>` element says "there must be a `Uri` on the `Intent`, and it must match the rules provided in the `<data>` elements of the `<intent-filter>`". In your particular case, the rule is "the `Uri` must exist and it must have a `content` scheme".

Since none of those three broadcasts uses a `content` `Uri`, delete the `<data>` element.

Answer (score 6):

for `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`, you just use this:

```
<receiver
  android:name=".UpgradeReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>



public class UpgradeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (!Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED.equals(intent.getAction()))
            return;
    ...  
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you run the app while instant-run is disabled, as noted [**here**](https://android.jlelse.eu/engage-your-android-users-with-new-content-after-app-upgrade-b8e160c4b0b8). I've noticed it doesn't always get received if it's enabled...

Comment: Its running in debug mode, i.e. UpgradeReceiver onReceive called. But in release apk it's not working. any suggestion?

Comment: @GiruBhai Should work. If not, it's either because of instant-run, or because the user chose "force stop" or similar.

Comment: I had tested with two *release* apks

Comment: Test better. Write to the logs using log.e("something") , for example. I've tested it now. Works well, unless you've never started the app.

Comment: release is proguarded, keep the name of the boradcastReceiver in your proguard files, it should be the first check to make for your "not running in prod" problem..

Comment: @MathiasSeguyAndroid2ee I don't think you need it in proguard rules. It should be available anyway, just like Activity, Service, etc... I don't see it in my custom list. I think it's in the default one.